# Alfresco: Run Javascript on Workflow Cancellation

Tags: javascript, scripting, alfresco

I have an advanced workflow that creates and modifies custom data list entries as different tasks are completed. However, if the user cancels the workflow, then the data list entry still persists.

**Is there an execution or task listener event on workflow cancellation that I can run Javascript from?**

Comment: It depends on your workflow,please add details of your customized workflow.

Answer (score 1):

Following webscript is called internally from **"Delete/Cancel workflow"** action.

```
   /alfresco/service/api/workflow-instances/{workflow_instance_id}?forced={forced?}
```

You can find related files here.

```
<ALF_HOME>\tomcat\webapps\alfresco\WEB-INF\classes\alfresco\templates\webscripts\org\alfresco\repository\workflow
```